# Migrate the existing custom Cordova plugin written in version 6.3 to 8.0. (MFP)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I would like to know what are the prerequisites to migrate plugin from v6.3 to 8.0. The code written for the plugin is in Java, should we any additional steps? or the same code(6.3) will continue to work for migration?

Can any one suggest any tool for plugin migration (like how we have for MFP Cordova application)?

Answer (score 1):

As of MFP 8.0, MFP client SDK is a Cordova plugin. If you have developed a custom Cordova plugin, this should work fine with MFP 8.0 as well. You can add your custom plugin to the Cordova project and use it as you would any other plugin.

Custom plugins are developed to meet specific requirements and the native implementation is specific to respective platforms. This is outside of MFP and there is no tool for custom plugin migration. Developer needs to do it themselves if a code change to their custom plugin is warranted.

Comment: @Vivin_K
Thanks for your valuable information. We will check it out.